# How to use a numpy function as the loss function in PyTorch and avoid getting errors during run time?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

For my task, I do not need to compute gradients. I am simply replacing `nn.L1Loss` with a numpy function (`corrcoef`) in my loss evaluation but I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Can’t call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead.
```

I couldn’t figure out how exactly I should detach the graph (I tried `torch.Tensor.detach(np.corrcoef(x, y)`) but I still get the same error. I eventually wrapped everything using with `torch.no_grad` as follow:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    predFeats = self.forward(x)
    targetFeats = self.forward(target)
    loss = torch.from_numpy(np.corrcoef(predFeats.cpu().numpy().astype(np.float32), targetFeats.cpu().numpy().astype(np.float32))[1][1])
```

But this time I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected np.ndarray (got numpy.float64)
```

I wonder, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    predFeats = self(x)
    targetFeats = self(target)
    loss = torch.tensor(np.corrcoef(predFeats.cpu().numpy(),
                                    targetFeats.cpu().numpy())[1][1]).float()
```

---

You would avoid the first `RuntimeError` by detaching the tensors (`predFeats` and `targetFeats`) from the computational graph.
i.e. Getting a copy of the tensor data without the gradients and the gradient function (`grad_fn`).

So, instead of

```py
torch.Tensor.detach(np.corrcoef(x.numpy(), y.numpy())) # Detaches a newly created tensor!
# x and y still may have gradients. Hence the first error.
```

which does nothing, do

```py
# Detaches x and y properly
torch.Tensor(np.corrcoef(x.detach().numpy(), y.detach().numpy()))
```

---

But let's not bother with all the detachments.

Like you rightfully fixed, it, let's disable the gradients.

```py
torch.no_grad()
```

Now, compute the features.

```py
predFeats = self(x) # No need for the explicit .forward() call
targetFeats = self(target)
```

I found it helpful to break your last line up.

```py
loss = np.corrcoef(predFeats.numpy(), targetFeats.numpy()) # We don't need to detach

# Notice that we don't need to cast the arguments to fp32
# since the `corrcoef` casts them to fp64 anyway.

print(loss.shape, loss.dtype) # A 2-dimensional fp64 matrix

loss = loss[1][1]
print(type(loss)) # Output: numpy.float64
# Loss now just a simple fp64 number
```

*And that is the problem!*

Because, when we do

```py
loss = torch.from_numpy(loss)
```

we're passing in a number (`numpy.float64`) while it expects a numpy tensor (`np.ndarray`).

If you're using PyTorch 0.4 or up, there's inbuilt support for scalars.

Simply replace the `from_numpy()` method with the universal `tensor()` creation method.

```py
loss = torch.tensor(loss)
```

P.S. You might also want to look at setting `rowvar=False` in `corrcoef` since the rows in PyTorch tensors usually represent the observations.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, `rowvar` can be set to both `True` or `False` because I am only using `corrcoeff` for two vectors.